# How do I do single command line command on multiple lines in windows?

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there a way to extend a command line command on to multiple lines in windows?

Of course, one can simply keep typing, and wrap around, what I'm wondering is if there is a character that you could put at the end of the line that would be a signal that the command is not yet complete.  This could be helpful in formatting a large command, and I've seen this in other command line environments.

Comment: windows cmd is multiline

Comment: Edited my question for clarity

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the carat `^` to extend to the next line.  For instance:

```
cd\^
program files\^
foo_directory
```

Will get parsed as:

`cd\program files\foo_directory`

Comment: Can this be used for batch files?