# Inserting \r\n into parameter on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe, escape-characters

I'm using FFmpeg on Windows where I need to insert an `\r\n` in a parameter itself.

```
ffmpeg … -headers "X-Test: Test\r\nX-Test-2: Test 2\r\n" …
```

While this will work fine under Linux and such, it does not work from a normal Windows 10 command prompt.  It also does not work under Bash under Windows.  In both cases, a literal `\r\n` (backslash, r, backslash, n characters) are sent in.

I have tried using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>13</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>10</kbd>, and while this appeared to insert characters, they were interpreted as `0xE299AA 0xE29799` by FFmpeg.

This question is similar to [How can I insert a new line in a cmd.exe command?](https://superuser.com/q/150116/48624), except that I'm not tied to cmd.exe.  I'm happy to use any shell as long as I can use it under Windows, if there are any suggestions.  Is this possible via Powershell somehow?  Or, maybe by putting my parameters in a text file and bringing it in as a parameter value?

Comment: Do you want a solution for Bash, Powershell, or cmd?

Comment: @EBGreen Doesn't matter... any of these are fine as long as it's for Windows.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT That works in PowerShell's command line!!!  Thanks!  Do you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: There you go just as you suggested with the example logic I've used in the past.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Yes, that's what worked!  Real simple, thanks.

Comment: Cool, I just edited my answer to reflect that more accurately—glad to help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell, you can use [image: backtick-r-backtick-n] and use backticks in place of the backslashes before the `r` and the `n` for the `CRLF` portions of the command—*backtick "r" backtick "n"*.

This only requires this change to the existing command

```
ffmpeg … -headers "X-Test: Test`r`nX-Test-2: Test 2`r`n"
```

---

### Further Resources

- [Escape characters, Delimiters and Quotes](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html)

  > ```
  > Special characters
  >
  >   Special characters are used to format/position string output.
  >
  >   `r`n  Carriage return + New line
  > ```
- **Backtick Key**

  [image]

Comment: How do I parse the `stdout` for `wmic logicaldisk get size,name,caption`?? i know `\r\r` will chop up all of the lines, but im lost beyond that :(

Comment: well, im doing everything from a nodejs script, so ideally i believe i need a command prompt command. exactly, ideally i would simply like all of the values comma separated with no column value for each disk in an array. [i posted a question about it here](https://superuser.com/q/1513664/650420), but it got closed due to lack of details lol

Comment: [ive reposted the question here](https://superuser.com/q/1513761/650420) so that it can receive responses

Answer (score 1):

Bash has `$'…'` syntax for this. It should work regardless of the OS.

```
ffmpeg … -headers $'X-Test: Test\r\nX-Test-2: Test 2\r\n' …
```

From [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting):

> Words of the form `$'string'` are treated specially. The word expands to `string`, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard. Backslash escape sequences, if present, are decoded as follows:
>
> […]
>
> `\n`
> newline
>
> `\r`
> carriage return
>
> […]

Answer (score 0):

Pure batch solution. Much worse than powershell of course so it's for reference only

```
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Get CR and LF characters
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"

(set LF=^
%=EMPTY=%
)

ffmpeg … -headers "X-Test: Test!CR!!LF!X-Test-2: Test 2!CR!!LF!" …
```

However it's unlikely that you really need the CR character because the C library will automatically convert between `'\n'` and the native new line character(s) on input/output so you just need to use LF