# Parsing Command Prompt Output

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, wmic, parsing

I am retrieving disk information via JavaScript with the `wmic` statement, `wmic logicaldisk get freespace,name,size,volumename`, which produces the following output, but in a single string.

```js
"FreeSpace      Name  Size           VolumeName  "
"560232755200   C:    999526756352   System      "
"999369699328   D:    999558213632   SSD         "
"1511570386944  E:    8001545039872  Get         "
"4620751712256  F:    8001545039872  BR          "
"788449492992   G:    4000650883072  Seen        "
"2296009408512  H:    4000768323584  Seen 2      "
"3594248679424  I:    8001545039872  2160        "
"3507750227968  J:    8001545039872  1080        "
"945300619264   K:    999625322496   Trailers    "
```

I parse the above output with the following JavaScript.

```js
window.onload = function(){
  const cp = require('child_process')
  let drives
  cp.exec('wmic logicaldisk get freespace,name,size,volumename', (error, stdout)=>{
    drives = stdout.trim().split('\r\r\n')
      .map(value => value.trim().split(/\s{2,0}/))
      .slice(1)
  })
}
```

That JavaScript already produces my desired output. It produces an array of nested arrays. Each row of information in the command prompt output corresponds to a nested array. Each nested array has four values that correspond to the originally queried data points.

```js
[
  ["560232439808",  "C:", "999526756352",  "System"  ]
  ["999369699328",  "D:", "999558213632",  "SSD"     ]
  ["1511570386944", "E:", "8001545039872", "Get"     ]
  ["4620751712256", "F:", "8001545039872", "BR"      ]
  ["788449492992",  "G:", "4000650883072", "Seen"    ]
  ["2296009408512", "H:", "4000768323584", "Seen 2"  ]
  ["3594248679424", "I:", "8001545039872", "2160"    ]
  ["3507750227968", "J:", "8001545039872", "1080"    ]
  ["945300619264",  "K:", "999625322496",  "Trailer" ]
]
```

I am wondering whether or not there is a way to similarly parse the information, but with command prompt instead?

Answer (score 1):

I believe its in part because of your regex you have

```
 .map(value => value.trim().split(/\s+/))
```

the /\s+/ is grabbing every all white space in the output from what I tested

I wrote up a quick regex string that may help though it is a bit messy and likely wont catch everything. I tested it with the output your provided though and it did the job. So its worth a shot.

```
/(\d)*(\s)*(\w:)(\s)*(\d)*(\s)*(\w(\s)?)*/gim
```

Comment: omg u know what. i didnt even think of that. i could just edit my regex query to `/\s{2,}/`, which should work like a charm. thanks so much dude. do you know if theres a way to achieve the same result purely with the `wmic` or command prompt statement?

Comment: No sorry, all i can think of right now is that your regex was catching the white spaces which was causing the issue, i was working a bit revised regex string since mine was messy, but with a improved regex you should be able to refine the output and what gets put into the array 

heres a slightly less messy regex string i made which ignores whitespace and should individually catch the data.

/(\d)*(?:\w)*(\w:)*(\d)*(\w( )?)/

Comment: your regex does not work. are you sure youre using JS regex? anyways, ive modified my regex statement to `/\s{2,}/` which works like a charm and shouldnt have any problems. im going to leave the question open to try and get some more answers, but if it doesnt receive any and you remind me in a day or two ill mark your response as the answer!! thanks again <333

Answer (score 0):

The issue from `wmic` output is just the carriage return (CR) character. It's possible to workaround that in cmd but it's a lot messier because of unfixable legacy issues and the lack of tools. That's why instead of fixing that MS just write a new shell named PowerShell from scratch. Please just use PowerShell for new code and avoid cmd. Try the below commands and you'll get a nicely formatted list immediately. You can then do any manipulation on the list easily

```powershell
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk | Select-Object Name, FreeSpace, Size, VolumeName
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk | Format-List -Property Name, FreeSpace, Size, VolumeName
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk | Format-List -Property *
```

In case you really want to do in cmd then here's the code

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Get CR, LF and TAB characters
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"

(set LF=^
%=EMPTY=%
)

for /f "delims= " %%t in ('forFiles /p "." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo(0x09"') do set "TAB=%%t"

rem Parse the command
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk get freespace^,name^,size^,volumename') do (
    set "line=%%a"
    rem Remove the CR character from each line
    for /f "delims=" %%c in ("!CR!") do set "line=!line:%%c=!"
    rem Parse each line
    for /f "tokens=1-3,* delims= " %%f in ("!line!") do (
        echo %%f !TAB! %%g !TAB! %%h !TAB! %%i
    )
)
```

Volume name can contain spaces so you must use `*` for the last token to capture everything. Sample output:

```
C:\>wmic logicaldisk get freespace,name,size,volumename & parse_wmic.bat
FreeSpace      Name  Size           VolumeName
87090261312    C:    248695820288   Windows 10
189214661732   E:    637248991232   Data
               F:

FreeSpace        Name    Size    VolumeName
87090261312      C:      248695820288    Windows 10
189214661732     E:      637248991232    Data
F:
```

As you can see many drives (like CD/DVD drives) don't have a size or name so the parsing will break. You'll need more code to fix that if you use cmd. It'll also break if you need any columns that can contain spaces after VolumeName. In that case it's extremely hard to tokenize